# Sequelize - how to omit middle-table's rows while including?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

For example, If I have:

```
User.findOne({
    ...SOMETHING,
    include: {
        model: Post,
        include: {
            model: Comment
        }
    }
});
```

This one returns:

```
{
    id: 1,
    ...user data,
    post: [{
       ...post data, // <--- I WANT TO OMIT THESE
       comment: [{
           ...comment data
       }]
    }, {
       ...post data, // <--- I WANT TO OMIT THESE
       comment: [{
           ...comment data
       }]
    }]
}
```

Then, I want to omit all the post data. I am only interested in comment data.

#### So, What I expect is:

```
{
    id: 1,
    ...user data,
    post: [{
        comment: [{...}]
    }, {
        comment: [{...}]
    }]
}
```

or

```
{
    id: 1,
    ...user data,
    comment: [{...}] // combined all comments into one array
}
```

I tried it with `attributes` option:

```
User.findOne({
    ...SOMETHING,
    include: {
        model: Post,
        attributes: [], // <--- expected: nothing shows
        include: {
            model: Comment
        }
    }
});
```

but the above code returns only user data:

```
{
    id: 1,
    ...user data
}
```

#### That's all.

There are no post or comment data. (I tried also `attributes: ['comment']`, but as you know, it occurs error)

I'm pretty sure that this is very simple problem but I cannot find any solutions to it. How can I omit the middle-table's rows? Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: Try "Exclude" withing attributes. Ex: attributes:[{ exclude: post fields except comment }].

Comment: @SaurabhGhewari No It doesn't work to me. It returns only user data without any comments.